# C++ templated method disambiguation rules with rvalue references

Tags: c++, c++11

In the following example the ctors #1, #1, #4 and #4 are called (in that order). I would expect #1, #1, #2, #3 to be called instead (discounting [RVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization)).

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct A
{
    A(){}                   //  1

    A(A&&){}                //  2

    A(const A&){}           //  3

    template<typename T>
    A(T&&){}                //  4

    template<>
    A(A&&){}                //  5

    template<typename T>
    A(const T&){}           //  6
};

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
A wtf(){ A x; return x; }

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main( int, char*[] )
{
    A a;
    A c = wtf();
    A b(c);
}
```

What's going on and why?!

Note: Remove #5 to compile with GCC (it's not that important anyway) - the above does compile with VS2010. I would be interested to hear if the results are the same in GCC if anyone can test it.

Comment: FWIW this doesn't compile under GCC 4.5 (http://ideone.com/xcqVF)

Comment: What I'm getting with G++ (4.4) (-fno-elide-constructors) is (a) #1 (c) #1 #2 #2 - it takes one constructor call just to return a value and one to use it; (b) #4. The last object would be constructed with the regular copy constructor if c were const. - But then again, 4.4 probably doesn't get many things right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a compiler bug.

Forgetting discussions about implicit rvalues for `return local` expressions (and `throw local` expessions too, by the way), this is clearly a compiler bug because --

**none** of the templated constructors should have been called in your example code.

No template function can be considered a copy constructor, copy assignment operator, move constructor, or move assignment operator.

C++11 support is patchy, although gcc's is [the best](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C%2B%2B0xCompilerSupport) it's still incomplete and buggy.

Comment: +1: Correct. 12.8/2 and 12.8/3 say "non-template", and 12.8/6 further solidifies this by saying that member function templates are never instantiated to produce copy/move ctors.

Comment: To workaround this problem I used SFINAE to cause substitution failure in the problematic templated methods when T == A

Answer (score 0):

You are having way too many constructors for a real class. This doesn't happen except in test code.

Constructor #4 with `T` being `A&`, and `A& &&` collapsing to `A&`, would be a better match for `A b(c)` than either #2 (`c` is not an rvalue) or #3 (`c` is not const).

Comment: Thanks for the partial explanation.
This is happening in real code for me. I have a class which constructs another class so it has a number of constructors which take a number of templated arguments as rvalue refs to perfect forward them.
Additionally I want a regular copy ctor and move ctor but as it is they never get called properly.

Answer (score -1):

`return x;` does not call the move constructor because `x` might not be expiring. In general terms it's just an lvalue like any other. `return std::move( x );` is usually necessary. (**EDIT:** but see next paragraph.)

There is a special rule that requires the compiler to perform a move operation instead of copy elision if a potential elision is not performed, §12.8/32. I'm not sure why you're not seeing that. Perhaps the compiler overlooked that rule because they don't expect the user to turn off elision.

You might expect the copy constructor `A( A const & )` to perform the `return` copy, but the template `A( T && )` implements perfect forwarding. `T &&` is deduced to `A &`, which is not `const` and therefore a better match.

Be very careful with perfect forwarding combined with copy constructors. I'm a bit surprised the language doesn't special-case this. As far as I know, the solution is to use SFINAE to disable the template under that circumstance.

Comment: -1 "*`return x;` does not call the move constructor because `x` might not be expiring.*", "*`return std::move(x);` is necessary.*" No -- there's a special rule for return values that implicitly makes them rvalues (FDIS §6.6.3/2), so in this case either NRVO will apply and no additional construction will take place or the move constructor will be called automatically.

Comment: ildjarn: Interesting, §12.8/32. Do you think the compiler is wrong or do you have a theory why he sees this result? Also, thanks for the downvote. That's really constructive. Edit: Ah, now I see you've owned up to the downvote, but 6.6.3/2 is not the relevant paragraph.

Comment: §12.8/32 appears to me to agree with §6.6.3/2; did you mean to imply that it validates or negates what I said? In any case, the OP never mentioned what version of GCC he's using, but I can say with _almost_ certainty that he's just observing a compiler bug. __EDIT:__ §6.6.3/2 says "*A copy or move operation associated with a return statement may be elided or considered as an rvalue for the purpose of overload resolution in selecting a constructor*" -- how is that not perfectly relevant? And I "owned up" to the downvote over 20 minutes ago -- refresh more. ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn: I saw your comment 3 minutes after you posted it… not in the habit of refreshing that much. 6.6.3/2 refers to 12.8 and "may be" doesn't really say a whole lot. OP mentioned he's using MSVC and the GCC I downloaded yesterday agrees with his results. Anyway, I've edited now, is this more to your liking?

Comment: Like ildajrn points out, half of your answer is wrong. However, and I don't know why I didn't think of this myself, SFINAE is exactly the fix to my problem that I needed and part of your explanation regarding it is correct. I'm not going to mark this as the answer though since it's not entirely correct.

Comment: @Potatoswatter : VC++ 2010 was based on N3000, so it's very likely that the relevant standard wording changed before the FDIS was published. (And in any case, VC++ has the least trust-worthy front-end that I've ever seen, and I say that as a MS VC++ MVP.) Regarding your edit, "*`return std::move(x);` is usually necessary.*" is still wrong -- it's __never__ necessary.

Comment: @Dave: I have fixed it. The automatic move is restricted to cases where "the criteria for elision of a copy operation are met or would be met save for the fact that the source object is a function parameter". So, I think iljarn's point is a bit misleading… it is interesting in the case of a pass-by-value argument, but that's not what you're doing.

Comment: @ildjarn: Re-read 12.8/32 and my preceding comment to @Dave. The implementation can't just decide to `move` everything you `return`; `move` is destructive while `return` is not!

Comment: @Potatoswatter : I have read the standard, and I stand by my statement. Assuming no (N)RVO, `return` _is_ destructive -- regardless of move or copy -- to the object being returned.

Comment: @ildjarn: If you return an lvalue referring to a member of `this`, it is not considered an rvalue and not moved unless you say `return std::move( member );` Do you disagree?

Comment: @Potatoswatter : No, I don't disagree with that. I do disagree that this in any way applies to the OP's question though.

Comment: @ildjarn: Perhaps we should move this to chat. It applies to my answer because `return std::move( x );` is indeed usually necessary. In real life, we don't leave copy elision turned off.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3510/discussion-between-potatoswatter-and-ildjarn)

Comment: @Potatoswatter : 1) `return std::move(member);` is always necessary, `return std::move(local);` is never necessary; given that moving a class' data member without moving the class object as a whole is pretty unusual, I'd still say that generalizing to "*`return std::move(x);` is usually necessary.*" is incorrect. 2) I would continue this in chat (Really! I **love** pedantic discussions :-D), but I'm just leaving for a prior engagement.

Comment: @ildjarn: I mean it is necessary to obtain a `move`, not what we do in practice.